# one button click disable others button in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, design-patterns, user-controls

I have an application with 2 tabs which are A and B. Both of the tab has 2 buttons. Besides out of the tab got 1 OK button. (refer to screenshot)

[image]

I have *3 view models*, which are *SampleApplication*, *Tab A* and *Tab B* and do binding.

Sample Application XAML

```
  <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
    <TabControl TabStripPlacement="Left" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Margin="5">
        <TabItem Width="190" Margin="1">
            <TabItem.Header>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="Tab A" Margin="5,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </StackPanel>
            </TabItem.Header>
            <TabItem.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ptab:TabA />
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabItem.ContentTemplate>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Margin="1">
            <TabItem.Header>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="TabB" Margin="5,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </StackPanel>
            </TabItem.Header>
            <TabItem.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ptab:TabB />
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabItem.ContentTemplate>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</DockPanel>
```

Sample Application View Model

```
 public class SampleApplicationViewModel
{
    private TabAViewModel tabAViewModel;

    public TabAViewModel TabAVM 
    {
        get { return tabAViewModel; }
        set { tabAViewModel= value; }
    }

    private TabBViewModel tabBViewModel;

    public TabBViewModel TabBVM 
    {
        get { return tabBViewModel; }
        set { tabBViewModel= value; }
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        tabAViewModel= new TabAViewModel();
        tabBViewModel= new TabBViewModel ();
    }
}
```

How to implement

1. when I click Tab A Button 1 or 2, buttons in Tab B and OK will be
   disabled.
2. When click OK button, Tab A or B buttons will be disable.
3. If click on Tab B Button 1 or 2, Tab A and Ok button will be disable.

*(disable around 5-10sec, then will buttons will enable back)

no using prism framework and etc.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are thinking about the issue incorrectly. The question isn't "How do I disable these buttons?" The question should be "What state is the 'enabledness' of the buttons tied to?"

To get this to work, the buttons command handlers need to set some variable (state) that causes the other buttons to disable. Note that this means there is a (possibly undesirable) dependency between your two tabs, but with your requirements, that was probably unavoidable.

Basically, you need to have your buttons look like:

```
<Button IsEnabled="{Binding SomeProperty}" Command="{Binding SomeCommand}"/>
```

Where "SomeProperty" is changed by a function that is invoked by the other "SomeCommand" handlers (for the other buttons).

Hopefully thats clear! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Hi @BradleyDotNET, am I able to use this approach by following this example ? http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28081/How-to-place-all-WPF-commands-and-related-events-c

Comment: No, that article solves the issue I raised with the other answer. I avoid static classes whenever possible, so I would not use this approach unless I had to.

Comment: hi, will try above statement you had mentioned later, thanks ya

Comment: hi @BradleyDotNET here is the link of the sample that I have created, please feel free have a look and help suggest are there any ways to improve or apply patterns. https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=233e2a690341bb1d

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `ICommand` you can subscribe the buttons to each others `CanExecuteChanged` event so the dependent button can enable itself once each respective `CanExecuteChanged` is raised. You would have to add a `CanExecuteChanged_Handler` to each command so when the handler is called you can check who the sender was and change its canExecute state.

Comment: That would likely be difficult to do cross-user control. I think you are on the right track (kind of) but this needs a lot more detail. Also, `CanExecute` and `CanExecuteChanged` are *really* hard to work with :(

Comment: @BradleyDotNET i agree with you. he would have to find a common place where he can initialize those ICommand.

Comment: @berkeleyjuan hi guys, thanks for reply and will do update answer soon xD